# Expandable sections closes when clicking on the content

Tags: visualforce, slds

I have implemented the [Expandable Section](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/expandable-section/) from SLDS in Visualforce.

The issue I'm currently facing is that when I click on the content (i.e. the text in the screenshot) it collapses the section. I want the section to collapse only when I click on the section's header.

[image]

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardController="Contact" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" docType="html-5.0" applyBodyTag="False" applyHtmlTag="False">
    <html>
        <head>
            <apex:slds />
        </head>
        <body class="slds-scope">
            <div class="slds-section">
                <h3 class="slds-section__title">
                    <button aria-controls="expando-unique-id" aria-expanded="true" class="slds-button slds-section__title-action">
                        <svg class="slds-section__title-action-icon slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_left" aria-hidden="true">
                            <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/apexpages/slds/latest/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#switch"></use>
                        </svg>
                        <span class="slds-truncate" title="Section Title">Financial health</span>
                    </button>
                </h3>
                <div aria-hidden="false" class="slds-section__content" id="expando-unique-id">
                    <p>
                        Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                        amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script>
                //add click event to each Expandable Section
                const expandableSections = document.querySelectorAll(".slds-section");
                expandableSections.forEach((item) => {
                    item.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
                        expandOrCollpaseSection(event);
                    });
                });
                function expandOrCollpaseSection(selectedSection) {
                    //check if section is open, if open close it
                    if (selectedSection.currentTarget.classList.contains("slds-is-open")) {
                        //remove the slds-is-open
                        selectedSection.currentTarget.classList.remove("slds-is-open");
                    } else {
                        selectedSection.currentTarget.classList.add("slds-is-open");
                    }
                    selectedSection.preventDefault();
                }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably change it to:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".slds-section__title");
```

Your current code listens for a click anywhere on the section and toggles it, you want it only on the title area.

Comment: I assume I will also need to change this part?
selectedSection.currentTarget.classList.remove("slds-is-open");

It won't be currentTarget anymore, right?

Comment: @Json Correct: `function expandOrCollpaseSection(section) { let selectedSection = section.target.closest(".slds-section"); /* rest of code is the same */`

Comment: I got the following error on row 4: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined"
https://pastebin.com/ZRjeHn2V

Comment: @Json Oops. Take out all the `currentTarget` bits. currentSection should point to the correct DOM element after the closest() call.

Comment: @Json Also, you could have just used `classList.toggle('slds-is-open')` instead of the if statement.

Comment: @Json                 `function expandOrCollpaseSection(section) { section.target.closest(".slds-section").classList.toggle("slds-is-open"); section.preventDefault();  }`

Comment: As always, thank you very much!